# % of value found in - DAX measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to calculate in how many countries we can find 80% of products.

I have a Fact table with count of products and Country dimension.

Example of calculation:
| Country | Products % |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1 | 43%|
| 2 |  36%|
| 3 | 9% |
| 4 | 6% |
| 5 | 4% |
| 6 | 2% |

So in this case 80% of products has been found in 3 countries.

I have no idea how can I calculate using DAX. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you already sort your table by Product%, then you may first create a new column to return 1 for sum of countries Product% up to 0.80, return 0 for remaining the countries:

```
Status = 
var total = CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[Products %]),
    FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Products %]>=EARLIER(Sheet1[Products %])))
return
IF(total <= 0.8,1,0)
```

[image]

In your visualization, filter the status column to only display value of "1" (in your question, only 2 countries will be display for 80% of the products),

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a column with % values, the value must be calculated in measure.